# Matplotlib: how to set a tick label above a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: Not good]
This is the sine and cosine plot I draw using matplotlib. But the tick labels are below the plot and can hardly seen.

My python code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6), dpi=96)
plt.subplot(111)

X = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 256, endpoint=True)
C,S = np.cos(X), np.sin(X)

plt.plot(X, C, color="blue", linewidth=2.5, linestyle="-", label="consine")
plt.plot(X, S, color="red", linewidth=2.5, linestyle="-", label="sine")

plt.xlim(X.min()*1.1, X.max()*1.1)
plt.ylim(C.min()*1.1, C.max()*1.1)

plt.xticks([-np.pi, -np.pi/2, 0, np.pi/2, np.pi],
          [r'$-\pi$', r'$-\frac{\pi}{2}$', r'$0$', r'$+\frac{\pi}{2}$', r'$+\pi$'])
plt.yticks([-1,  1],
          [r'$-1$', r'$+1$'])

ax = plt.gca()
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data',0))
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data',0))

plt.legend(loc='upper left', frameon=False)


for label in ax.get_xticklabels()+ax.get_yticklabels():
    label.set_fontsize(16)
    label.set_bbox(dict(facecolor='green', edgecolor='None', alpha=0.2))


plt.savefig("figures/exercise10.png", dpi=120)
plt.show()
```

So, how should I set a tick label above a plot?

[image: Ideal effect]

Thank you!

Comment: The ideal effect plot is from http://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/teaching/matplotlib/. But even the same code, I can not get the target plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly you want to set the labels and the axes spines on top of the lines. This can easily be achieved with the `"axes.axisbelow"` rcParam.

```
plt.rcParams["axes.axisbelow"] = False
```

[image]

Comment: One more thing, now, the green block is behind the plot, and how should I move it to the front?

Comment: No, it only looks like the green block is behind the lines, due to its transparency. Use `alpha=0.7` or higher to see it more clearly.

Comment: If you have an axes instance (e.g. `ax = plt.subplot(111)`) then you could also use `ax.set_axisbelow(False)` see [documentation here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_axisbelow.html).